# Full width jQuery parallax scrolling carousel with rotating background image? (like Humaan.com.au)

Tags: jquery, carousel, parallax

I'm looking for a jQuery package to help me implement a full-width carousel that's very similar to the one at http://www.humaan.com.au/.  The key requirements are:

1. The background spans the entire browser width
2. The background image is high resolution
3. Various HTML items swoop in from the side or top at different speeds.  Each slide might have different animations for the HTML elements.
4. There are pagination buttons for going directly to a slide
5. It would be nice to have a loading icon like humaan has (which is similar to Zurb's orbit slider)

I've looked at sequence.js, which seems very close, but I couldn't find any demos that show it running full-width while rotating a background image.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's an image that basically summarizes my needs:

[image]

Comment: I think this is may help you out.
[http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout#/demos](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout#/demos)